# Loading a math font with stylistic set in plain XeTeX

Tags: fonts, math-mode, xetex, plain-tex, opentype

How does one activate a stylistic set in plain XeTeX?

I have tried:

```
\font\test="XITS Math:+ss01" % for calligraphic
\textfont2=\test
$ \fam2 A $
\bye
```

but with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course `A` gives an A, as any font has an uppercase A in the corresponding slot:

```
\font\testa="XITS Math:script=math;language=DFLT;"                   
\font\testb="XITS Math:script=math;language=DFLT;+ss01;" 

\textfont2=\testa
$  \XeTeXmathchar "0 "2 "1D49C $

\textfont2=\testb
$  \XeTeXmathchar "0 "2 "1D49C $
\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Umm, yeah, the question wasn't perhaps perfectly clear: I was trying to achieve a calligraphic A. So one needs the script mapping for the cal to kick in, huh? Thanks!

Comment: You have to know what's its code point: `\cal A` works in Plain TeX because `\textfont2` has a calligraphic A in the slot corresponding to uppercase A. XITS Math has an A, there.

Comment: Yeah I know. Unicode doesn't have a reserved range for calligraphic (which is distinctive from script style), and different fonts use different ways for cal. The Unicode range for *script* is that 0x1D49C..0x1D4CF (accounting for both upper- and lowercase). What I *didn't know*, was that I needed to use the *script* range for the stylistic set -switch to kick in. In Asana Math, for example, the calligraphic range isn't available via stylistic set 1 on script-range.

Comment: @morbusg: Mapping script to calligraphic seemed the most logical choice to me because of the similarity between both (they are even seen sometimes as mere stylistic variants of the same math alphabet rather than two different alphabets.)

Comment: @KhaledHosny: sure, it is logical, but finding that information isn't, IMHO, exactly straight-forward. For instance, I found out by pure blind luck that Asana uses the "Stylistic Alternates" over script-range for calligraphic. I guess my point is this: I find it strange that Unicode doesn't define a standard way to reach calligraphic, seeing how very, very, common it is in mathematics.

Comment: @morbusg -- if you can find several math documents from "recognized" publishers that use calligraphic and script **in contrast to one another, with different meanings**, i can open the question of adding a calligraphic block with the unicode technical committee.  when the symbol set for the stix project was being developed, i couldn't find such examples, which is why they aren't distinguished in unicode.  everyone on the committee believed they were simply subjective alternates, either for "house style" or personal preference.  it's a hard sell.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: sure, I understand all you're saying. It's just that I've been under the impression that calligraphic is far more common than script. In the fonts I've seen,  script doesn't seem to lend itself very well for the legibility in maths compared to calligraphic. Do you know if there has been discussion whether they could've been other way around (i.e., the reserved block would've been for calligraphic)?

Comment: @morbusg -- calligraphic didn't really get started until don knuth adopted it for computer modern.  traditionally, math composition has used "real script".  that's not to say that there were many script fonts appropriate for this use; there weren't!  but the unicode committee goes with tradition whenever there's a clear one to be followed.  and since there are several *script* letters with long-standing associations (H = hamiltonian, for one) where calligraphic isn't accepted, that affected the decision.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Oh my, I had it all backwards, then. Thanks for the insights! (sorry egreg for all the noise)